# How to add a addTestDevice in Android studio

Tags: java, android, google-ads-api

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .build();

        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

```
ads:adSize="BANNER"
```

ads code is errorring

This is the Code But .addTestDevice is erroring how can ı add addTestDevice
This is the code thanks

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: error is adSize adSize attribute not found